# Specifying limit / offset for ContentProvider queries

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to get my ContentResolver to run this query:

```
select * from myTable limit 1 offset 2
```

The only **query** method in ContentResolver is:

```
resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

I've tried:

```
final Cursor c = resolver.query(
        MyTable.CONTENT_URI,
        MyTable.PROJECTION,
        " ? ?",
        new String[] {"1", "2"},
        null);
```

Which just throws an IllegaLArgumentException. 
What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12476458/1523910

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898043/how-to-add-limit-clause-using-content-provider

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I put the LIMIT clause in the sordOrder parameter, I've also seen the same thing done by others but not sure if its 100% correct:

```
final Cursor c = resolver.query(
        MyTable.CONTENT_URI,
        MyTable.PROJECTION,
        null,
        null,
        " limit 1 offset 2");
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd actually tried to use this and *thought* it wasn't working due to an outdated SQLQueryBuilder source version.. working now.

Comment: Your welcome, since your working with content providers I have a shameless plug! I am working on an open source DSL that makes it easy to write and maintain sqlite backed content providers, specific instructions here http://robotoworks.com/mechanoid-plugin/database-dsl/ visit the parent page for install instructions, I would warn its very alpha though but it still might be something of interest :)

Comment: I've confirmed that putting the limit clause in the sort order does work.

Comment: Otherwise the clause will be incorrectly appended to the underlying query resulting in an invalid SQL statement

Comment: This doesn't work for Android 11, `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token limit`

Comment: Not sure why the devs would call this 'abuse', `// Some apps are abusing "ORDER BY" clauses to inject "LIMIT"` from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#2200)

Answer (score 26):

I put the limit clause as a query parameter using the syntax 'limit = *offset*, *limit*':

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MyTable.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().encodedQuery("limit="+offset+","+limit).build(),
        MyTable.PROJECTION,
        null,
        null,
        null);
```

It works at least with MediaStore uris. Be careful of not encoding the "," or it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution, but I've solved the issue by now. :D

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer. Piggy backing LIMIT in the sort order is a terrible hack and can easily break the provider implementation.

Answer (score 25):

If you are providing your content provider, then you can use [`android.net.Uri.Builder#appendQueryParameter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#appendQueryParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for providing limit and offset as query parameters, which the content provider can use while building the query.

```
public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public static final String QUERY_PARAMETER_LIMIT = "limit";
    public static final String QUERY_PARAMETER_OFFSET = "offset";

    public Cursor query(Uri uri, ...) {
        String limit = uri.getQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAMETER_LIMIT);
        String offset = uri.getQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAMETER_OFFSET);

        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        // set the table name,...

        // leaving handling of null conditions as an exercise to the reader.
        String limitString = offset + "," + limit;

        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, limitString);

        //...

        return c;
    }
}
```

while building the query:

```
private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = MyProvider.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(MyProvider.QUERY_PARAMETER_LIMIT,
                    String.valueOf(limit))
        .appendQueryParameter(MyProvider.QUERY_PARAMETER_OFFSET,
                    String.valueOf(offset))
        .build();
```

note that the [`android.net.Uri.Builder#appendQueryParameter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#appendQueryParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) encodes the value to prevent sql injection.

#### References:

1. http://laviefrugale.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-limit-with-android-contentprovider.html
2. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476458/1523910 + [@eocanha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499177/1523910)

Comment: You're a couple years too late and I also have no way of verifying if this works, but thanks for the elaborate answer, I hope it helps someone!

Comment: @Buffalo, I am using this code in my apps, also I wrote here partly because, I can come back later just in case I was to "lose" the access to this code. There is simply too much to remember in android.

Comment: I like this approach the best, but it seems that limit and offset is reversed, so that building limitString should be written as: limitString = offset + "," + limit;

Comment: @nicolai, thanks for noticing, I have updated the answer to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @AvinashR Did you really update the answer? I don't see any edit. See the correct syntax for limit and offset. The offset should appear first! http://stackoverflow.com/a/3325580/313113 Otherwise, your answer is the best!

Comment: @MnemonicFlow, seems like you're right, anyways I've updated the answer with much cleaner version of using syntax `LIMIT <limit> OFFSET <offset>`. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: @AvinashR Yes, but that syntax is invalid. I've tried it and it gives `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid LIMIT clauses: LIMIT 10` because it accepts the OFFSET, LIMIT pattern . See line 208 and 40 in the SQLiteQueryBuilder source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java The regex for the limit string is `"\\s*\\d+\\s*(,\\s*\\d+\\s*)?"` which fails to match

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use the limit String [see limit String below] using the following:

```
 StringBuilder sbLimit = new StringBuilder().append(" ").append(i_offset).append(" , ").append(i_limit);
String limit = sbLimit .toString()
```

This gave me good results in combination with the select queries , sorting and grouping.